# Using setState from inside a reducer. Reducer updates state twice instead of once

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-reducer

I am new to React and I'm trying to build a calculator in React.js. I have a display that contains two fields: one to output the current value and the other one to store a "slice" of the expression. I'm basically trying to immitate the Windows calculator. I use useReducer hook to update state depending on the type of the button pressed. In the dispatch object, I send references to two useState hooks declared inside the App. These hooks are: (1) a useState boolean to indicate whether I am waiting for a second amount, and (2) a useState to save a slice of an expression so it appears in the paragraph above.

**The problem is in the reducer function**, in the `"multiplication_operator" case`. When I click on the multiplier sign for the second time, I expect the previous state array `['first amount', 'operator']` to concatenate with the `'second amount'`. Basically, I expect an array where index 0 is the first amount, index 1 is the operator and index 2 is the second amount. However, when I try to add the second amount at index 2, it adds the same second amount at the next index (3), which is unexpected. [Link to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/calculator-state-problem-mooyw8?file=/src/App.js:392-397)

[Link to gif that reproduces the bug](https://gifyu.com/image/SwKZn)

I assume the problem might come from the fact that I use and update too many states from inside the reducer function.

**My question is what is the source of the problem and how do I fix it?**
Is it the issue of poor choice of hooks or something else? Reducer triggers a chain of updates from App and then back to reducer? I'm really out of ideas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the correct behaviour for useReducer to be called twice. (Details here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16295)

For your app to work as intended despite this, you would have to store/update `value`, `firstNumber` and `operatorIsActive` **within the reducer** instead of calling `setFirstNumber` and `setOperatorIsActive` to update them.

e.g. you could set the initial state of your reducer as

```
const initialState = {
  value: "0",
  firstNumber: [],
  operatorIsActive: false
};
```

instead of just storing the initial value.

```
const initialValue = "0";
```

In App.js you can access the reducer values this way

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(displayValueReducer, initialState);
const {value, firstNumber, operatorIsActive} = state;
```

When the multiply button is clicked, you could access/update the values this way:

```
case "multiplication_operator": {
  const operator = ` ${action.value} `;
  if (state.operatorIsActive === false) {
    return {
      ...state,
      firstNumber: [state.value, operator],
      operatorIsActive: true
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...state,
      firstNumber: [...state.firstNumber, state.value]
    };
  }
}
```

Changes like the above would ensure that your reducer is pure (elaboration here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions-in-javascript/)

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you kindly for your answer.